# Water rushing through pipes every few seconds

Tags: plumbing

For the past two hours, there has been a sound of water rushing through pipes that lasts about 5 seconds before a loud thumping noise. After another 10 seconds or so the noise repeats.

What could be causing this? It started at a seemingly random time late in the night, when no water was running in the house in the first place.

I have checked all the spigots, all the faucets, the toilet, bath, dishwasher and washing machine, and none have any indication of a problem. Water pressure seems okay, with a very slight dip when the rushing noise starts until it ends.

Comment: Expect a larger water bill. Go in each bathroom and listen. Then jiggle the flush handle and see if it stops, do this for each bath. If this fails turn each fill valve for the toilet off and check in 1/2 hour to see which tank is low, that's the problem. You need to fix or replace it. Some have a chain, an over zealous flush will cause it to hang on something, check that on the bad unit.  If it were an ice maker you would have a lot of water on the floor. If it were the washer you would have water in the tub. If you do not find it turn the water off and wait to see if a neighbor has a problem.

Answer (score 3):

What sound like is happening is a valve/ solenoid is opening and then suddenly closing causing the "thump"   Logically the only things in the average home that could cause that is the toilets, washing machine, and icemaker. You didn't indicate if you were in a single family home, condo, apartment or such, so we have to assume the issue is with something in your home.
I would turn off the water supply to each of the above one at a time until you find the culprit. The repair will need to be addressed after the cause is known.

Comment: Would start with the toilet.  If the flush valve/flapper has started to leak a bit, it is hard to see the leak.  The water in the tank goes down a bit and then fills back up.  Acts the same way as OP states.

Comment: **Water softener**, if present  - or other backflushing canister filters (less commonly present but same automated valve issues) - often a source of hidden weird leaks, excessive water use, and other strangeness if it goes wonky.